# Spring Boot Rest Controller Array Handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hello Spring Developers

I have a spring-boot related issue, which I don't know how to resolve properly.

This issue is a direct consequence of spring's behaviour with query parameters:
When a single query parameter contains the `,` character it will be split by that comma.

Example:

```
XXX?array=1,2,3 => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

When a query parameter - containing the `,` character - is defined multiple times, spring will not split every value by the comma.

Example:

```
XXX?array=1,2&array=3 => ["1,2", "3"]
```

Issue: Some of our query parameters may contain a `,` character.

Since spring does not behave like the RFC is stated I need a way to NOT split the query parameters by commas.

**My Controller**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping(path = "arrays", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getArrayQueryParameters(@RequestParam("array") String[] array) {
        return Arrays.asList(array);
    }
}
```

**My Testcase**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Controller.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ControllerMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    // This Test fails
    @Test
    void oneParameter() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/arrays?array=1,2,3,4,5")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]", is("1,2,3,4,5")));
    }

    @Test
    void parameterTwoTimes() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/arrays?array=1,2&array=3,4,5")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]", is("1,2")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1]", is("3,4,5")));
    }

    @Test
    void parameterThreeTimes() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/arrays?array=1,2&array=3&array=4,5")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]", is("1,2")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1]", is("3")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2]", is("4,5")));
    }
}
```

You can find an example github repo here: https://github.com/arolfes/RestArrayParametersSample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make query params not split by commas using `@InitBinder` and `DataBinder`.

Spring `DataBinder` uses `StringToArrayConverter` for converting `String` to `String[]`, which behaves as you experienced. ([Related source codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToArrayConverter.java#L66))

Classes annotated with `@Controller` or `@ControllerAdvice` can have methods with `@InitBinder`.

You can utilize `registerCustomEditor()` of `DataBinder` to applying `PropertyEditor` which not using the comma delimiter.

If you add this method for your `ControllerServletRequest`, the first test case will succeed. (I checked.)

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(DataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor(null));
}
```

As you can see, I intentionally give `null` for constructor of `StringArrayPropertyEditor` because the arg is delimiter, whose default value is `","`. ([Related source codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4f8516e2c3ca420b1608840ab901bf9df7e4d5f1/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringArrayPropertyEditor.java#L69-L71))